# Is Toshiba L50-A-1CU compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, compatibility, toshiba-satellite

I am about to buy a [Toshiba L50-A-1CU laptop](http://www.toshiba.it/laptops/satellite/satellite-l50-a/satellite-l50-a-1cu/), but unfortunately it runs Windows 8 and it is not in the official Ubuntu compatibility list. Actually, Toshiba disappeared from the list completely.

Could someone confirm if Toshiba L50-A-1CU is compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: it looks like your link does not work, is this the correct link? http://www.toshiba.it/laptops/satellite/satellite-l50-a/satellite-l50-a-1cu/

Comment: http://www.toshiba.it/laptops/satellite/satellite-l50-a/satellite-l50-a-1cu/

Answer (score 1):

You are taking a risk, probably Ubuntu will work, but there are no guaranties.

the biggest risk I see by scanning the specs is that the laptop seems to has a nvidea optimus chip. I don't have personal experience, but I have heard there are some problems to get that to work properly. do some more research on that to make a educated decision.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this issue, Wouter. For this specific problem, though, it looks like Bumblebee project got what it takes to make it work.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html

Answer (score 0):

It will run ubuntu but if everything will work it's hard to say. If not now in near future for sure. Check [linlap](http://www.linlap.com/toshiba), linux-on-laptops and linuxhcl. People sharing their experience with different distros on different hardwares there.